# Android Studio won't start with OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: android-studio

After installing Android Studio on a Mac it does not start with this exception:

```
Cannot Lock System Folders: Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:1068)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.lock(FileChannel.java:1053)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.underLocks(SocketLock.java:174)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:121)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:319)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:143)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:76)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas where the problem can be?

Comment: This should be reported as a bug report onto the relevant bug/issue trackers instead of posting on StackOverflow. Anyways, it could be an issue with your file permissions possibly?

Comment: Won't start when there is 100% packet loss and studio will be Crash.

Comment: @Edric Thanks. I reported it on the trackers too. Do you have any idea, which permissions can be relevant?

Comment: I had my home folder on an extra disc. After I formated the disc and started with a clean home directory it worked.